# contenteditable not working in IE 10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, html-table, internet-explorer-10, contenteditable

I am trying to create client side editable table. Here is my code. It works in Chrome, Firefox but not in IE. Is there anything more to do with script for IE?

```
<script type="text/javascript"       src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("td").click(function(){
if($(this).attr("contentEditable") == true){
    $(this).attr("contentEditable","false");
} else {
    $(this).attr("contentEditable","true");
}
})
});
</script>

<p> 
<table id='transitTable' border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" class='display'    width="400">
<tr id='1'>
<td >H1</td>
<td >H2</td>
<td >H3</td>
<td >H4</td></tr>
<tr id='2'>
<td >R1</td>
<td >R1</td>
<td >R1</td>
<td >R1</td></tr>
<tr id='3'>
<td >R2</td>
<td >R2</td>
<td >R2</td>
<td>R2</td></tr></table></p>
```

Answer (score 12):

There are many elements in IE, which can't have [`contenteditable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537837%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) set directly. However, you can wrap the whole `table` into a content editable `div`.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <table>
       ...
    </table>
</div>
```

This will [make all the cells in the table editable](http://jsfiddle.net/4CH5S/). Though in some browsers (FF) the view will be a bit messy due to the shown editing handles of the table.

Another possibility is to add for example a content editable `span` or `div` to each `td`.

Comment: @Teemu : hie. What if i want to make the inputbox uneditable ? contenteditable="false" is not working In IE9. Works well with chrome.

Answer (score 6):

IE is not response `contenteditable` inside `td` tag.

You can try:

```
<td id="my-content" class="editable">
    <div contentEditable="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        ...
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work in IE as well chrome without meshup the GUI.

```
   <td contentEditable="true">
    <div contentEditable="true">
        ...
    </div>
   </td>
```