# HTML Table Row Not Editable in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-explorer, contenteditable

I have a table where I can press an Edit button and you can edit a certain column in the table, then press the button again and save any changes that were made. If I am doing this on Chrome/Safari/Firefox, it works! However, when I use IE and I press the edit button, the column does not become editable like it does in the other browsers.

How would I be able to fix this problem in IE?

HTML Table:

```
<table id="skuTable" cellspacing="5" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th style="display: none">Product ID</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Major Category</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Minor Category</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="skuRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="skuRow">SKU Description</th>
            <th class="skuRow">SKU Status</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Create Date</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Group ID</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

         <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) { ?>

        <tr>
            <td style="display: none" class="prod_id" id="product_id-<?php echo intval ($row['Product_ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Product_ID']?></td>
            <td class="major_cat" id="major_cat-<?php echo intval ($row['Major Category'])?>"><?php echo $row['Major Category']?></td>
            <td class="minor_cat" id="minor_cat-<?php echo intval ($row['Minor Category'])?>"><?php echo $row['Minor Category']?></td>
            <td class="rep_code" id="rep_code-<?php echo intval ($row['Product Report Code'])?>" align="center"><?php echo $row['Product Report Code']?></td>
            <td class="sku" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU'])?>" align="center"><?php echo $row['SKU']?></td>
            <td class="sku_desc" id="sku_desc-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU Description'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU Description']?></td>
            <td class="sku_status" id="sku_status-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU Status'])?>" align="center"><?php echo $row['SKU Status']?></td>
            <td class="create_date" id="create_date-<?php echo intval ($row['Date'])?>" align="center"><?php echo $row['Date']?></td>
            <td class="group_id" id="group_id-<?php echo intval ($row['Group_ID'])?>" align="center"><?php echo $row['Group_ID']?></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit" onclick="enable_value(this)"></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#skuTable .edit", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
  });
  if ($this.val() === 'Edit') {
    $this.val('Save');
   if($this.id !== '.major_cat') {
        tds.not('.major_cat').not('.minor_cat').not('.rep_code').not('.sku_desc').not('.sku_status').not('.create_date').not('.sku').not('.sku_group').prop('contenteditable', true);

   }
  } else {
    var isValid = true;
    var errors = '';
    $('#myDialogBox').empty();
    var elements = tds;
    if (tds.find('input').length > 0) {
      elements = tds.find('input');
    }
    var dict = {}; 
    elements.each(function (index, element) {
      var type = $(this).attr('class');
      var value = (element.tagName == 'INPUT') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();
      console.log(type);
      // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
      switch (type) {
          case "sku":
              dict["SKU"] = value;
          break;
          case "group_id":
            if (!$.isNumeric(value)) {
                isValid = false;
                errors += "Please enter a numeric Group ID\n";
            }
            if (isValid) {
                dict["Group_ID"] = value.trim();
                }
        break;
      }
    })
if (isValid) {
    console.log(dict);
  $this.val('Edit');
  tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
  var request = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "update-index.php",
      data: dict
    });
} else {
  alert(errors);
}
  }
});
```

Comment: I think this would be infinitely simpler if you just toggled the `contentEditible` property of the cells.

Comment: Seems to me that this: `foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) { ?>` is an incomplete line of code.

Comment: What do you mean by incomplete?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [contenteditable not working in IE 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381991/contenteditable-not-working-in-ie-10)

Comment: Don't php expressions start with `<?`? That line seems to be a php statement without a beginning delimeter.

Comment: Oh yes you are right....I actually have it in my code and then a comment right afterwards. So  when I was cleaning up my code for the post, I deleted it with the comment. I will add that back in there