# ContentEditable Not Working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, contenteditable

I have an HTML table with an edit button in one column. When a user presses the "Edit" button, one of the columns should become editable. This works in Chrome/Safari/Firefox but it does not work in IE. It will allow me to press the edit button, however, once it is pressed, it will not allow any column edits to be made.

How can I make this function in IE as well? Is `contenteditable` compatible with IE? If not, what would be a workaround?

HTML:

```
<table id="merchTable" cellspacing="5" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th class="sorttable_nosort" style="display: none">ID</th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Loc</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="merchRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Special ID</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Description</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Quantity</th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Unit</th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

        <tr>
            <td style="display: none" class="id"><?php echo $row['ID'];?></td>
            <td class="loc"><?php echo $row['Loc'];?></td>
            <td class="rp-code" align="center" id="rp-code-<?php echo intval ($row['Rp-Code'])?>"><?php echo $row['Rp-Code'];?></td>
            <td class="sku" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU'];?></td>
            <td class="special-id" align="center" id="special-id-<?php echo intval ($row['Special-ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Special-ID'];?></td>
            <td class="description" id="description-<?php echo intval ($row['Description'])?>"><?php echo $row['Description'];?></td>
            <td class="quantity" align="center" id="quantity-<?php echo intval ($row['Quantity'])?>"><?php echo $row['Quantity'];?></td>
            <td class="unit" id="unit-<?php echo intval ($row['Unit'])?>"><?php echo $row['Unit'];?></td>
            <td><button type="button" class="edit" name="edit">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#merchTable .edit", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
  });
  if ($this.text() === 'Edit') {
    $this.text('Save');
   if($this.id !== '.quantity') {
        tds.not('.loc').not('.rp-code').not('.sku').not('.special-id').not('.description').not('.unit').prop('contenteditable', true);
   }
  } else {
    var isValid = true;
    var errors = '';
    var elements = tds;
    if (tds.find('input').length > 0) {
      elements = tds.find('input');
    }
    var dict = {}; 
    elements.each(function (index, element) {
      var type = $(this).attr('class');
      var value = (element.tagName == 'INPUT') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();
      console.log(type);
      // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
      switch (type) {
        case "id":
              dict["ID"] = value.trim();
          break;
        case "quantity":
        if ($.isNumeric(value)) {
              dict["Quantity"] = value.trim();
          break;
          } else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a numeric value\n";
            break;
          }
      }
    })
    if (isValid) {
        console.log(dict);
      $this.text('Edit');
      tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
      var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "update.php",
          data: dict
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row updated");
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to updated");
            console.log(response);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // Log the error to the console
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });
    } else {
      alert(errors);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381991/contenteditable-not-working-in-ie-10

Comment: @Steve This is html and would set the entire table to be editable...if I am correct, wouldn't I need to use javascript for this certain problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, it seems that contentEditable is implemented differently in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

In Internet Explorer contenteditable cannot be applied to the TABLE, COL, COLGROUP, TBODY, TD, TFOOT, TH, THEAD, and TR elements directly, a content editable SPAN, or DIV element can be placed inside the individual table cells (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533690(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Would there be a simple way to change my javascript in order to fix the problem?

Comment: Have you seen this example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms533690(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Rataiczak24  Added plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/G1mLMazjAwlxRrqTm42a?p=preview Tested in IE 11 with Emulation. I hope it will work for you

Comment: I see that it works in IE 11 but I cant figure out how to implement that into my current code